# Probability of exactly x independent events occurring with unequal probabilities

Tags: probability

I have 20 independent events with unequal probabilities and need to programmatically determine the probability of exactly x of the events occurring. Are there any elegant solutions to this type of problem?

Here's an example of a case:
I want to know the probability of 3 events occurring:
prob of event 1 = 0.432, prob of event 2 = 0.012, prob of event 3 = 0.001, prob of event 4 = 0, prob of event 5 = 0, prob of event 6 = 0.012...

Comment: What are the probabilities and what is the value of $x$?

Comment: Do you know about probability generating functions? Those could give a very elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @HugoBerndsen, I do not, do you have a good resource to learn about them?

Comment: @barakmanos, I added an example to my question.

Comment: You can split it into disjoint cases (each case consisting of $3$ events), calculate the probability of each case (a product of the $3$ events of that case), and add up the results. For $3$ out of $20$ events, you have $1140$ cases. I might be able to give you a Python script.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand your comments correctly, you have Bernoulli variables. So they either happen or do not happen with a certain chance $p_i$.

The not-elegant but straightforward way is to use a convolution, specifically if $X_i$ is the stochastic variable for the $i^\text{th}$ event, with \begin{equation}
P(X_i=1)=p_i \qquad \text{and} \qquad P(X_i=0)=q_i=(1-p_i).
\end{equation}
The chance that $n$ of the events happen is written as 
\begin{equation}
P(\sum_i X_i=n)=\sum_{S} \prod_{i\in S} p_i,
\end{equation}
where $S$ are all selections of subsets of length $n$ from your set of events.

The elegant way could use probability generating functions. These are power series defined as
\begin{equation}
G(z)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)z +P(X=2)z^2 +\ldots
\end{equation}
For your Bernoulli problem this is pretty easy:
\begin{equation}
G(z)_i=(1-p_i)+p_i z
\end{equation}
This is then the probability generating function for the $i^\text{th}$ event. This function can now basically be seen as a nice way to group your chances. But now the nice part comes in. **If you want to calculate probabilities for the sum of stochastic variables, you can just take the product of their probability generating functions!**

So, you now get
\begin{equation}
G(z)_{\text{sum}} = \prod_i G(z)_i = \prod_i \left((1-p_i)+p_iz\right).
\label{gener}
\end{equation}

Now you have found the PGF for the sum. The only thing you still have to do is find your probabilities back from the sum. So, you have a power series and you need the coefficients. You can do this by taking derivatives:
\begin{equation}
P(\sum_i X_i=n)=\frac{1}{n!} G^{(n)}(0)_{\text{sum}},
\end{equation}
where you thus have to take the $n$th derivative of the previous function. You can do this by using a product rule.

Does this help? I hope that you at least found it interesting. You can read more about it at this [site](http://www.am.qub.ac.uk/users/g.gribakin/sor/Chap3.pdf).